# What does an Access Key do for a Label in .NET Windows forms?

Tags: .net, windows, winforms, access-keys

Someone enlightened me yesterday to the fact that Labels can have access keys.  So I set a Label's text property to `Class &A` and, indeed, it now has an underline and everything.  As far as I can tell, though, Labels can't get the focus.

So what does this Access Key do; if nothing, then why are they allowed anyway (TextBoxes do not have Access Keys)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use [Label.UseMnemonic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic.aspx) with an "access key", and then press that access key (ie: *Alt+A* in your example), the control next in the tab order (based on [TabIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex.aspx)) on the form will receive focus.

Comment: As the question says, the Label cannot get the Focus.  If you hit Alt while it's running, the underline shows up, but hitting the key does not move to the Label (because the Label can't be moved to).  What then does it do, if anything?

Comment: @dafrazzman No - as I said, when you hit the key, it moves to the control on the form next in the Tab order (past the label itself).  Label can still have a TabIndex set - so you get the label's TabIndex +1 gets focus.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I apologize for being too proud to read your answer correctly (hypocrisy on my part).  That's good to know!  Thanks!